# Android internal storage - File is full then empty from Activity to another

Tags: android, json, file, internal-storage

I have an issue with Android internal storage: One of my `Activity` create a `JSONArray` and write it to a file called `my_profile.json`. When I log the file, everything is ok.

This `Activity` (`DefaultProfile`) is called before the `MainActivity`.

When I log the file in the `MainActivity`, everything is also good, file exists, and full of my data.

But here came the strange parts, when I try to read it from some other `Activities`, it's empty but the file exists:

```
String[] files = fileList();
        for (String file : files) {
            Log.e("OtherActivity", file);
        }
```

Here is the Log.d

```
D/MainActivity: my_profile.json
D/WeekActivity: my_profile: []
```

Now the even stranger thing is that when I restart my app, the file is empty even in the `MainActivity`.

Here is the `static` methods from my util `Class` I use to read/write this file:

Read:

```
static public JSONArray loadJsonArray(File path, String file) {
        String jsonString;
        JSONArray jsonArray;
        try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path.getPath() + file);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            jsonString = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        }
        catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            if (e instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
                return new JSONArray();
            }
            getStackTraceString(e);
            return null;
        }
        return jsonArray;
    }
```

Call:

```
JSONArray profile = JsonFileUtil.loadJsonArray(getFilesDir(), "/my_profile.json");
```

Write:

```
static public void writeToJson(File path, String file, JSONArray jsonArray) {
    Writer output;
    File outFile = new File(path, file);
    if (jsonArray == null) {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    }
    try {
        outFile.createNewFile();
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
        output.write(jsonArray.toString(2));
        output.close();
    }
    catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        getStackTraceString(e);
    }
}
```

Call:

```
JsonFileUtil.writeToJson(getFilesDir(), "/my_profile.json", profile);
```

Comment: It seems that you pass a null `jsonArray` to `writeToJson` method and it creates an empty array as this `if (jsonArray == null) {` implies, so when you read the file you got an empty list. Run your code in `debug` mode and put a `break point` to see if the array is null or not.

Comment: Thank you @Merka ! The error was nof in the first writing, but my MainActivity call a Volley request that retrieve the user profile and write it to the file. Guess what ? I disabled the POST request in the DefaultProfile for testing and didn't enabled it later. Never code after 5 AM ...